# how use protocol buffers?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I watched a lot of tutorials, but I can not understand how to use protocol buffers

Why "message User "? why not "class User "? and how Eclipse has created such a message?
and why name = 2 ? not name = "Max"

```
ption java_outer_classname="ProtoUser";

message User {

   required int32  id = 1;  // DB record ID
   required string name = 2;
   required string firstname = 3;
   required string lastname = 4;
   required string ssn= 5; 



   // Embedded Address message spec

    message Address {
      required int32 id = 1;
      required string country = 2 [default = "US"];; 
      optional string state = 3;
      optional string city = 4;
      optional string street = 5;
      optional string zip = 6;



      enum Type {
         HOME = 0;

         WORK = 1; 

       }

       optional Type addrType = 7 [default = HOME]; 

 }
   repeated Address addr = 16;
}
```

Comment: where you get this file from? and what is exactly is your question?

Comment: I want to make a simple example protocol buffers

Comment: See the answer. It seems that you didn't read the manual carefully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why "message User "? why not "class User "?

Google Protocol Buffers (GPB) does not have `class` in its syntax, it has `message` instead.
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/style

This file is just text file, it should have `.proto` extension. After all you will run a utility on it which would generate real Java classes which you can import and easily use in your project.

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial

Compiling Your Protocol Buffers

```
protoc -I=$SRC_DIR --java_out=$DST_DIR $SRC_DIR/addressbook.proto
```

`required string lastname = 4;`

4 stands for the **field id**, not a value, it is going to be used to generate a bit stream.

Comment: I do not have any experience with compilation, I could not understand "Compiling Your Protocol Buffers

protoc -I=$SRC_DIR --java_out=$DST_DIR $SRC_DIR/addressbook.proto...."

Comment: use CMD? $SRC_DIR ? $DST_DIR ?

Comment: Compiling means to generate real Java files, to include in the project code. Yes, use `cmd` to run `protoc`. SRC_DIR is where the proto file is, DST_DIR where you want to put generate java file.

Answer (score 0):

Protobuffer use message(keyword) instead of class
Inside the class you define the structure of. schema.
For example

```
 message Person{
  string name = 1;
  repeated string id = 2;
  Type phoneType = 3;
 }

enum Type{
 CellPhone = 0;
 HomePhone = 1;
 }
```

In the above example, we are defining the structure of the Person Message.
It has name which datatype is a string, id which is an array of the string and type(when you expect only certain values then use an enum. In this case, we assume that phoneNumber can be either CellPhone or HomePhone. If someone is sending any other value then IT will through UNKNOWN proto value exception)

required: means parameter is required

To use proto first create proto classes using mvn clean install
Then create protobuilder
Protobuilder to set for above proto

```
 Person person = Person.newBuilder().setName("testName")
 .setPhoneType(Type.CellPhone)
 .addAllId(listIds)
 .build;
```

Once you set the value you can not change it. If you want to change the value then you need to create another proto.
Pesron person1 = Person.newBuilder(person).setName("ChangeName").build;

person1 will have the name ChangeName, phoneType CellPhone, and ids arrays of strings.

More information:  https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers